# Can you get a list with all messages in a msmq?

Tags: powershell, queue, message

I am trying to check if any messages in all my msmq have been there more than 2 minutes via script. I tried powershell but the closest I got was getting how many messages are in a private queue, but does not seem to be any option to get the messages in a variable to see their arival time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer in another thread, it is exactly what I was searching for.

```
[String]$cName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging") | out-null
[System.Messaging.MessageQueue[]]$queues = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::GetPrivateQueuesByMachine($cName.ToLower())
Foreach ($queue in $queues) {
$queue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll()
try {
    [System.Messaging.Message]$message = $queue.Peek(10)
    Write-Host $queue.QueueName $message.ArrivedTime
}
catch {
    #Write-Host "Timeout"
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should list all the messages in all queues, going through them all.

Use this as a base and expand.

```
gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_msmq_msmqqueue -computerName $computerName |
    ft -prop Name, MessagesInQueue
```

Comment: I got to this point using a variation of this command already, but this returns a list of all the queues and my problem is that a queue object does not seem to have a method that returns a list of messages that are in that queue.